# Setting system wide http(s)/ftp proxy with username and password on Ubuntu/Mint

Tags: linux, proxy, passwords, linux-mint

At my office I was given a pac file in order to connect to our proxy. The pac file is just a bunch of ignore-this-internal-site-and-that-local-site along with a proxy for other connections, let's call it `proxyname.office.uni.ac.za:3125` (there is no `http://` or something simmilar in the link).

My problem is that the proxy requires a username and password. When set system wide through either the configuration url (using the pac file) or plainly with the raw proxy,
[image: Linux Mint proxy settings]

some programs play nice (like Chrome and Firefox) and dislays a username/password dialog as soon as they open. Other programs such as apt-get and most basically everything just can't connect. Dropbox at least gives username and password fields in its proxy settings,
[image]

but still can't function correcly when trying to use the system-wide settings.

I have tried the following without results:

- setting the system-proxy as `username:password@proxyname.office.uni.ac.za:3125`
- setting the system-proxy as
  `http://username:password@proxyname.office.uni.ac.za:3125`, 
  `https://username:password@proxyname.office.uni.ac.za:3125`, 
  `ftp://username:password@proxyname.office.uni.ac.za:3125`.
- setting the proxy in the pac file as `username:password@proxyname.office.uni.ac.za:3125` wherever `proxyname.office.uni.ac.za:3125` is found (and using this pac file system wide).
- setting the proxyin the pac file as `http://username:password@proxyname.office.uni.ac.za:3125` wherever `proxyname.office.uni.ac.za:3125` is found (and using this pac file system wide).

Is there any way to set this proxy system wide with a preset username/password? Or is there any program that can maybe setup a new proxy (let's say `localhost:1234`) proxying the other username/password proxy with it's username/password preset. Or is there something else I can try or have missed?

Comment: squid (with cache_peers configuration) + iptables (to create transparent proxy)

Comment: Which Linux distro? Can you use [this Ubuntu solution](http://tuxdiary.com/2013/11/29/apply-system-wide-proxy-settings-on-ubuntu/), or the [proxy-login-automator](https://github.com/sjitech/proxy-login-automator)?

Comment: I am using Mint 17.3. I have a bit of a deadline so @ssnobody, I will check squid and iptables probably over the weekend, thanks.

Comment: @harrymc, I will try the proxy-login-automation and give feedback.

Comment: End up figuring anything out?

Comment: Nope, I remember that `proxy-login-automation` did run without error, but absolutely nothing happened. I had a readup on the other setup you mentioned (squid and iptables), but the first few steps I took made me realise that the learning curve to solving my problem is quite steep when using this. At the end I just gave up and used our activate-my-mac-on-the-network-and-pay-for-data option, which is quite expensive. (I work for an university and the referred proxy is a gift for our office, but such a hassle to use).

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, so i created the tool [proxy-login-automator](https://github.com/sjitech/proxy-login-automator)

Just following the example, you can create a fake local proxy server which forward requests to the real yet auto inject user/password.